# How can I size all rows to evenly fill all the height of a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a WPF application that follows the MVVM pattern. The View contains DataGrid (from WPF Toolkit) that displays some information and supports paging. I want the rows number to depend on the DataGrid's size. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you need to do.

Comment: I need to calculate the rows number that fit the current size of the DataGrid.

Comment: Ok, that's a good start. You want to adjust the number of rows displayed in the datagrid based on the size of the datagrid.  Still not enough info.  Do you have a fixed size for your datagrid; Do you have a fixed size for your row height?  Posting your code always helps.

Answer (score 0):

RenderSize is size.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.windows.uielement.rendersize.aspx
From datagrid size and row size you should be able to calculate how many row can fit on a single screen.